# Strapi Authentication Issue

Tags: reactjs, strapi, nuxt-strapi

I am currently using Strapi as my backend and am having issues with authentication.

When I hit `/api/auth/local`, the user is created in the strapi backend and the jwt token is created.

After that, I try to hit `/api/users/me` and the endpoint returns a 404. I have the user permissions for an authenticated user turned on (find, findOne, and me) but am still getting this error.

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi Brian, can you tell me please the version of strapi you are using? IF your installetion is ok it should not give a 404 (not found) error. You said to set permissions so no 403, also no 405 in case you used other method than GET. have a check on node_modules/@strapi/plugin-users-permissions/server/routes/content-api/user.js for the method get with path '/users/me' maybe it's not there.

Comment: Hey @CristianCimuca, thanks for the reply! I actually figured it out, my url for the GET request was undefined because it wasn't properly reading my env file. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me out!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, was appearing error 500 all the time, because the user was blocked. After change, worked for me.

[image]

I follow these explanation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rju99LTUNA